# Need help on google SSO when navigating one app to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm having an ASP.Net MVC app configured to use google authentication. I'm having another app which is also configured to use google SSO.

When navigating first app to second app when multiple user active google logins are available, I do not need the user to select the google account from choose account screen. I'm expecting do a token based authentication in the second application so that the app tp app navigation is seamless and the second app will authenticated with the correct google account.

Is there a way to do it or possible documentation or guide on how to do it.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code describe what issues you are having with your current solution.   The only way to avoid the user selection screen is to use login hint.

Comment: There's the `login_hint` optional parameter in [their OAuth2 flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server). This should be helpful here.